# Unexpected behavior with GADTs in z3, got value that is equal to every integer

Tags: python, z3, z3py

This will be the right question for someone with a deeper understanding of `z3` or interest in its quirks.

Hi There, I'm running the following test to understand how GADTs work in `z3` python. It seems like the value `unfoo(bar(foo(b)))` is equal to any integer? Is this right?

The below is a valid test - can you help explain why it works?

```
import pytest
from z3 import Datatype, Solver, IntSort, Int

def test_stackoverflow():
    FooBar = Datatype('FooBar')
    FooBar.declare('foo', ('unfoo', IntSort()))
    FooBar.declare('bar', ('unbar', FooBar))
    FooBar = FooBar.create()

    foo = FooBar.foo
    unfoo = FooBar.unfoo
    bar = FooBar.bar
    unbar = FooBar.unbar

    solver = Solver()
    solver.push()
    a = Int('a')
    b = Int('b')
    solver.add(a == unfoo(bar(foo(b))))
    assert str(solver.check()) == "sat"
    model = solver.model()
    assert model.evaluate(a).as_long() == 1
    assert model.evaluate(b).as_long() == 0
    solver.pop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing indeed, but I think z3 is doing the right thing.

It's easier to see what's going on if we dump the generated SMT-Lib. (Add `print solver.sepxr()` before you call `check`.) I get:

```
(declare-datatypes ((FooBar 0)) (((foo (unfoo Int)) (bar (unbar FooBar)))))
(declare-fun b () Int)
(declare-fun a () Int)
(assert (= a (unfoo (bar (foo b)))))
```

It takes a bit of staring, but here're the types involved:

- `b` is `Int`
- `(foo b)` is a `FooBar`, but in particular it has the constructor `foo`.
- `(bar (foo b))` is a `FooBar`, but in particular it has the constructor `bar`.
- `(unfoo (bar (foo b))` is an `Int`, but it applies the `unfoo` selector to something that is constructed with a `bar`.

And therein lies the issue: You have "destructed" a term with something that was built with something else.

The typical 'SMTLib' answer for such scenarios is "underspecified." That is, the logic makes no promises about what holds, and thus the solver is allowed to instantiate in any way it wants. So, the model you got is correct; though kind of confusing.

To see this better, imagine how you would code this in a language like Haskell:

```hs
data FooBar = Foo {unfoo :: Int} | Bar {unbar :: FooBar}
check a b = a == unfoo (Bar (Foo b))
```

Let's try: (`ghci` is the Haskell interpreter):

```
ghci> check 1 0
*** Exception: No match in record selector unfoo
```

Ah! It tells us that we messed up. Can we fix it? Here we go:

```hs
data FooBar = Foo Int | Bar {unbar :: FooBar}

unfoo :: FooBar -> Int
unfoo (Foo i) = i
unfoo (Bar _) = 1  -- Conveniently pick the result here!

check a b = a == unfoo (Bar (Foo b))
```

We get:

```
ghci> check 1 0
True
```

Voila! Note how I defined `unfoo` myself to make this "satisfiable".

Essentially, z3 does the same thing. Since the `unfoo` destructor applied to something constructed with `bar` is underspecified, it just picks an interpretation that makes the problem satisfiable. To sum it up, when you define a destructor like `unfoo`, what you are saying is:

- If you receive a `foo` value, then give me what's inside
- If you receive a non-`foo` value, then give me whatever you please; so long as it's of the correct type and satisfies my other constraints.

And that's precisely what Z3 did for you. I hope that's clear. Cool example though!